# How to make View stop grow at parent's height?

Tags: android, textview

This is the code. The reference point is parent's height. The text should grow until it reaches its parent's height. However the element keeps growing beyond visible area.

There is no need to post XML file as there is only one button and one textview.

Anyone knows why the text keeps growing beyond the parent's height? What am I doing wrong?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        final int screenWidth = display.getWidth();
        final int screenHeight = display.getHeight();

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int dTextWidth = textView.getWidth();

                if (dTextWidth <= screenHeight) {
                    textView.setTextSize(textView.getTextSize() + 1);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Thanks

---

**EDIT**

I used `LinearLayout`'s height and it still does not work. Even more, **the `LinearLayout` height is 0** !!!!!

```
LinearLayout lin = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
final int layoutHeight = lin.getHeight();
Toast.makeText(this,"LinLay height: "+layoutHeight,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
...
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int displayTextWidth = textView.getWidth();

                if (displayTextWidth <= layoutHeight) {
                    textView.setTextSize(textView.getTextSize() + 1);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: hierarchyviewer will help you

Comment: How? What should I look for? Which element is making this not to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing the text width with the screen height. It's a simple mistake.
Change it to this.

```
if (dTextWidth <= screenWidth) {
    textView.setTextSize(textView.getTextSize() + 1);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it will grow to the width. I do not want to stop there. I want it to grow until the parent's height because the text view can auto-break the line. The text has more than 1 word so I want to have 3 big words on the screen.

Comment: Okay. Looking at the documentation for `Display` object, [Display.getHeight()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getHeight()) , it says "This should not generally be used for computing layouts, since a device will typically have screen decoration (such as a status bar) along the edges of the display that reduce the amount of application space available from the raw size returned here." So, instead of using the "device" height, use the height of the application's root view.

Comment: Hm, excellent point! Thanks. I will edit the post accordingly.